# Joining 3 columns into 1 with pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a txt file with 5 columns, where I need to merge together columns 1,2,3; and 4 and 5. Merged items should be separated by :. I am new to coding, so will appreciate any help
Like this

```
a1  111111  333333  A   D
b1  222222  444444  B   E
c1  333333  555555  C   F


a1:111111:333333    A:D
b1:222222:444444    B:E
c1:333333:555555    C:F
```

I guess it can be done with pandas, but the problem is that columns do not have titles in my file 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In *Pandas* a DataFrame must have column names.
Assume that your source DataFrame (with column names) contains:

```
   C1      C2      C3 C4 C5
0  a1  111111  333333  A  D
1  b1  222222  444444  B  E
2  c1  333333  555555  C  F
```

To generate your expected result, you can e.g.:

1. Define a function to be applied to each row:

   ```
   def newRec(row):
       return pd.Series([f'{row.C1}:{row.C2}:{row.C3}', f'{row.C4}:{row.C5}'],
           index=['C1', 'C2'])
   ```

   Note that usage of a *f-string* with embedded references to individual
   columns allows you not to care about type of each column.
2. Apply this function:

   ```
   result = df.apply(newRec, axis=1)
   ```

The result is:

```
                 C1   C2
0  a1:111111:333333  A:D
1  b1:222222:444444  B:E
2  c1:333333:555555  C:F
```